# why isnt my table able to form on sql oracle? can anyone help me revise it to work?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, revision

I am trying to create this table and I am not sure why it wont run or let me

```
  CREATE TABLE DRIVER (
    DRIVER_ID           INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY,
    DRIVER_NAME         VARCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
    DRIVER_ADDRESS      VARCHAR (35)    NOT NULL,
    DRIVER_CITY             VARCHAR (35)    NOT NULL,
    DRIVER_STATE            VARCHAR (2)     DEFAULT ‘TX’,
    DRIVER_ZIP          INTEGER (5) NOT NULL
    );
```

This is the data I'm trying to insert into the table

```
INSERT INTO DRIVER (DRIVER_ID, DRIVER_NAME, DRIVER_ADDRESS, DRIVER_CITY, DRIVER_STATE, DRIVER_ZIP) 
VALUES (‘3452342’, ‘Jennifer Kay, ‘2345 Green Ave’, ‘Dallas’, ‘TX’, ‘75201’);
VALUES (‘4323462’, ‘Alex Sanchez’ , ‘326 Main Street’, ‘Plano’ , ‘TX’, ‘75074’);
VALUES (‘7994638’, ‘Rob Joe’, ‘4315 Campbell Road’ ‘Mesquite’, ‘TX’,’75150’);
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: What does "won't run or let me" mean?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Please don't make us guess.  You've specified 3 `VALUES` clauses but only one `INSERT` which won't work.  In your post, you have the Microsoft curly quotes in your `DEFAULT` rather than normal single quotes.  I have no idea whether either is your problem or whether those are transcription errors on your part.

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFAULT ‘TX’,
```

there are wrong quote characters. It should be `DEFAULT 'TX',`. The same problem in insert statement.